# During ping, packet capture shows Ip fragmentation happens differently for different sets of hardware, is that expected

Tags: networking, network-programming

I am quite new to the this, i have a query regarding the IP fragmentation during ping. i have set an mtu size for 200 for one of the interface and doing ping with packet size 700. I have captured the pcap and could see the following

for one of the hardware variant i get 5 packets of size (218*4, 64) 5 ipv4 Fragments (708 bytes): #50(176), #51(176), #52(176), #53(176), #54(4) and for other hardware variant i get 4 packets of size(218*3,222). 4 ipv4 Fragments (708 bytes): #74(176), #75(176), #76(176), #77(180)

last fragment is having 180 instead of 176 is this difference in behavior is normal or not? in any of the case could you please explain why and what is happening here.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For MTU size 200 and no IPv4 options, IPv4 header size is 20. So, maximum payload size is 180.

IP fragment offsets are measured in units of 8 byte blocks. This means that all fragment payload lengths (except the last one) must be a multiply of 8.
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Fragmentation_and_reassembly)

So, both cases are correct, but the latter one is more optimal.

Comment: "_This means that all fragments lengths (except the last one) must be a multiply of 8_" should actually read "_This means that all fragment payload lengths (except the last one) must be a multiple of 8_".

Comment: Thanks Ron and Andriy for the inputs. To add on further I noticed that the kernel version is different in both the hardware variants one is 4.4 and other is 4.9. not sure if it has caused any impact.